# Subset data and store before passing, using loc

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, data-science

```
Face ID Manipulation    mean
Condition       Manipulated None


 0    101 Averageness4.428571 3.400000
1   101 Femininity  4.235294    3.625000
2   101 Masculinity 3.666667    4.000000
3   101 Symmetry    4.047619    3.809524
4   102 Averageness 3.695652    2.611111
... ... ... ... ...
431 96  Symmetry    1.565217    1.684211
432 98  Averageness 3.882353    3.333333
433 98  Femininity  2.789474    3.318182
434 98  Masculinity 3.440000    3.800000
435 98  Symmetry    3.473684    3.347826
```

436 rows × 4 columns

I've first had to pivot my data and store it in a variable called pivoted.

From this DataFrame, I'm trying to create four sub DataFrames called "avg, sym, masc, and fem", which store the filtered data so that I can analyse it.  I'm not sure how to approach this.

Instructions: From this DataFrame (pivoted), create four sub DataFrames called avg, sym, masc, and fem, which store the filtered data. Then, pass those to the t-test function of pingouin, referencing the None and Manipulated columns and display the result. There should be four displayed tests.

This is what I have so far:

```
 # Pivot data
 pivoted = pd.pivot_table(by_faces, index=['Face ID', 'Manipulation'], columns= 'Condition', 
 values='Numeric_Score')

display(pivoted.reset_index())

# Pull out sub-dataframes
avg = pivoted.loc[Manipulation['Averageness'] =='Manipulated','None']
sym = pivoted.loc[Manipulation['Symmetry'] =='Manipulated','None']
masc = pivoted.loc[Manipulation['Masculinity']=='Manipulated','None']
fem = pivoted.loc[Manipulation['Femininity'] =='Manipulated','None']

#carry out t-tests with pingouin and display directly, four lines needed
 avg1 = pg.ttest(avg['Manipulated', avg['None'],paired= True)
 sym1 = pg.ttest(avg['Manipulated', avg['None'], paired= True)
 masc1= pg.ttest(avg['Manipulated', avg['None'], paired= True)
 fem1 = pg.ttest(avg['Manipulated',avg['None'], paired= True)
```

my outputs are to reflected the following t-test results:

For symmetry, (M = 3.02,SD = 1.49)
symmetrical versions (M = 3.00, SD = 1.46); t(108) = 0.68, p = 0.498, and d = 0.07.

For averageness (M = 3.50,SD = 1.36) as compared to No manipulation (M = 3.10, SD = 1.36); t(108) = 9.14, p < 0.001, and d = 0.88

For femininity (M = 2.98, SD = 1.58)or more feminine versions (M = 3.03, SD = 1.59); t(108) = 1.11, p = 0.271, and d = 0.11.

Finally, for masculinity(M = 3.15, SD = 1.44) compared to normal (M = 3.51, SD = 1.37); t(108) = 8.10, p < 0.001, and d = 0.78.

Comment: Could you add an input example and an expected output?

Comment: Please edit the question and add it to your code

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.Dataframe(byface)

avg = df[df['Manipulation']=='Averageness']
sym = df[df['Manipulation']=='Symmetry']
masc= df[df['Manipulation']=='Masculinity']
fem = df[df['Manipulation']=='Femininity']
```

The dataframe is segregated according to Manipulation. You can pivot the newly created dataframes using pivot_table, though it's not necessary and pass the values of 'manipulated' and 'none' columns to t-test function of pingouin.

Comment: Is it possible to see what it looks like using pivot_table?